# Postgres query taking a long time when counting

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I've got an index for a table in Postgres, and trying to speed up a query to count elements.

Simplified, this is the table and index:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id                          uuid,
  deployment_id               uuid,
  started_at                  timestamp,
  ended_at                    timestamp,
  notes                       text,
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS A_by_deployment_id ON A(deployment_id, started_at desc);
```

Essentially, we want to be able to count the items in a time range, and then give accurate counts for when those items are filtered on certain fields. When I don't include any filters, the count is very quick. But when I run this query (note the `notes <> ''` as an example query):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A
WHERE deployment_id = 'XXXX'
AND notes <> ''
AND date_trunc('day', '2023-01-01T05:00:00.000Z') <= started_at 
AND started_at <= date_trunc('day', '2023-09-10T03:59:59.999Z') + interval '1 day'
```

it gives a very long runtime:

```
Aggregate  (cost=1947306.09..1947306.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=139313.811..139337.476 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=32473.34..1947306.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=139299.726..139323.384 rows=0 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on A  (cost=31473.34..1946305.99 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=139236.212..139236.216 rows=0 loops=3)
              Recheck Cond: ((deployment_id = 'XXXX'::uuid) AND (started_at <= ('2023-09-09 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone + '1 day'::interval)))
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3021055
              Filter: ((notes <> ''::text) AND ('2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone <= started_at))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 220895
              Heap Blocks: exact=19014 lossy=130950
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_by_deployment_id  (cost=0.00..31473.34 rows=636542 width=0) (actual time=317.141..317.142 rows=620293 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((deployment_id = 'XXXX'::uuid) AND (started_at >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (started_at <= ('2023-09-09 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone + '1 day'::interval)))
Planning Time: 0.251 ms
Execution Time: 139386.633 ms
```

The total execution time of >2 minutes seems poor for <1 million rows. Without the filter, we can get the range quickly with an Index Only scan. It looks like it then needs a Heap Scan that takes a very long time. Can I get any help in optimizing this behavior?

Edit: Here's is the "EXPLAIN (analyze, verbose, BUFFERS)":

```
Aggregate  (cost=1947318.09..1947318.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=241608.194..241613.857 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(*)
  Buffers: shared hit=7 read=465248
  I/O Timings: read=692920.945
  ->  Gather  (cost=32485.34..1947318.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=241608.176..241613.837 rows=0 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=7 read=465248
        I/O Timings: read=692920.945
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on A  (cost=31485.34..1946317.99 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=241581.932..241581.933 rows=0 loops=3)
              Recheck Cond: ((A.deployment_id = 'XXXX'::uuid) AND (A.started_at <= ('2023-09-09 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone + '1 day'::interval)))
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3020692
              Filter: ((A.notes <> ''::text) AND ('2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone <= A.started_at))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 220880
              Heap Blocks: exact=19672 lossy=133295
              Buffers: shared hit=7 read=465248
              I/O Timings: read=692920.945
              Worker 0:  actual time=241577.148..241577.150 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=1 read=152982
                I/O Timings: read=229432.745
              Worker 1:  actual time=241578.565..241578.567 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=2 read=153127
                I/O Timings: read=229433.323
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_by_deployment_id  (cost=0.00..31485.34 rows=636542 width=0) (actual time=5072.596..5072.597 rows=620293 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((A.deployment_id = 'XXXX'::uuid) AND (A.started_at >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (chats.started_at <= ('2023-09-09 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone + '1 day'::interval)))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=6174
                    I/O Timings: read=4641.102
Query Identifier: 2755043791582677827
Planning Time: 16.373 ms
Execution Time: 241617.394 ms
```

Comment: Could add `buffers` and `verbose` to your explain? `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` to get the complete picture, especially IO.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Just added that. I'm not sure I know how to understand it.

Comment: Try `AND started_at BETWEEN date_trunc('day', '2023-01-01T05:00:00.000Z')
AND  date_trunc('day', '2023-09-10T03:59:59.999Z') + interval '1 day'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an index-only scan just be including "notes" into the index as a third column.  Better yet, build a partial index with the same columns, but with a WHERE clause matching `notes <> ''`.  With the first one, you could eliminate the wrong "notes" directly in the index without needing to visit the heap making random IO calls.  With the 2nd, you could eliminate them automatically, without even needing to see them in the index.

Also, your work_mem seems to be too low for your type of query, leading to the high Rows Removed by Index Recheck.  However, this is not actually the problem here, because such rechecks are done on other rows in the same table pages you would otherwise need to visit.  Since you bottleneck is IO, you need to make it visit fewer pages, not check fewer rows in the same set of pages.  But presumably increasing work_mem may be important for other related queries.